# Calculadora de figuras geométricas

Tags: java

Este segundo ejercicio que estoy haciendo es una calculadora que realiza el cálculo de área de tres figuras, la idea es que el programa lo que hace es tener un menú que escoja el número de lados, a través de eso pedirá :

1. si es un solo lado , círculo, pedirá solo un valor
2. si es de dos lados, cuadrilátero, pedirá solo el valor de uno de ellos o sino, de dos de ellos
3. si es de tres lados, el triángulo deberá calcularse su área a través de la fórmula general ya conocida por todos, deben ingresarse los tres lados y hacerse la operatoria:

Hasta aquí llevo pero me da la impresión de que hay que modularizar un poco y sacar cosas del main para que no quede tan lleno, además de crear una clase que herede las otras tres figuras.

Va bien? que le falta?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
class FiguraGeometrica {
    public int numeroLados = 0;
    public static double PI = 3.14;
    public String queFiguraEs = "";
    public void main (String[] args) {
    }
    public boolean escogerFigura(){
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la calculadora de Geofiguras");
        System.out.println("Seleccione una figura: ");
        System.out.println("1.Círculo, 2.Cuadrado, 3.Triángulo");
        char seleccion = lector.nextLine().charAt(0);
        switch(seleccion)
        {
            case '1':
                queFiguraEs = "Círculo";
                numeroLados = 1;
                break;
            case '2':
                queFiguraEs = "Cuadrado";
                numeroLados = 2;
                break;
            case '3':
                queFiguraEs = "Triángulo";
                numeroLados = 3;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error, por favor escoja opciones 1,2 ó 3");
                break;
        }
      System.out.println("Es un " + queFiguraEs + ".");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println("Por favor solo números del 1 al 3");}
    return true;
    }
    public boolean validarInput() {
        return false;
    }
}
class Círculo extends FiguraGeometrica{
    public void sacarArea(double area, double lado1){
        area = (lado1*lado1*PI);
    }
}
class Cuadrado extends FiguraGeometrica{

    public void sacarArea(double area, double lado1){
        area = (lado1*lado1);
        }
}
class Triangulo extends FiguraGeometrica{
    public void sacarArea(double area, double lado1, double lado2, double lado3){
        area =( 0);
    }
}
```